# Is it possible to scale specific apps on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, scaling

We know that with the Windows 10 feature Display Scaling is possible to change the size of text, apps and icons.
Once you set a value, this is applied to ALL texts, apps and icons.
I just want to set this feature for specific apps.
One example: 125% is set to default, but when I use an IDE like Eclipse or Visual Studio I want the scaling at 100%.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible.

Right-click the .exe of the program that is not to be scaled,
choose Properties, go to the tab Compatibility, click
"Disable display scaling on high DPI settings", finally click OK.

Comment: What if the default is 250% and we want to set blurry apps to 200%?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 8):

Thanks!

Windows changed "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" to:

Change high DPI settings > (Checkbox) Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by: Application.

Just had to select "Application" from the drop down menu and now, all apps run on 125% and the app I open runs on 100%.