# What is the best solution to show the invisible area of a window when it's too big?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

I am using Windows 10, and now I have a very HUGE window, like this:

[image: Demonstration]

My screen is not as big as the window, and the window is not resizable, so some areas are invisible to me.

What should I do to display the invisible area?

I only have one screen.

Comment: Alt+Space then M would allow you to move the window with arrow keys

Comment: And hit enter once the window is in its desired position.

Comment: @phuclv won't work. You cannot move above the upper or left limit of the screen because this snaps to the mouse cursor.

Comment: Google a picture of what it looks like and how many buttons there are. Working blind, press tab until it presumably gets to the button you want. Hit enter. You'll get pretty good at it after having to install Windows in 480p where hitting cancel could cost you an hour. - "Windows 10" running what program? "WindowSlider can not slide windows up and down." but it's your accepted answer. So did you see the whole image or not? If you tell me what it is and it's free I could SS it for you. If it wasn't free, "Contact the developer is right."

Comment: BTW, most Linux window managers make this easy.  Alt+left-click will let you drag a window around, grabbing from the point you clicked so you can push the title bar up off the top edge, letting you see the bottom of a large window.  (I think this alt+left shortcut is enabled by default in most X11 window managers; it is in KDE and Fluxbox.)  That doesn't help with Windows, unless a similar shortcut can be enabled there.

Comment: I figured I'd test ALT+PRTSCR (which would make a screenshot of *only* the active window) with a window that's half outside of the desktop, so you at least have some way of seeing the contents... Unfortunately it only captures that portion of the window that's within the desktop area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can move a window by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd>
of its entry in the taskbar.

Choose the "Move" option and use the arrow keys to move the window
in the right direction, horizontally or vertically.

As this feature is implemented in a strange way by Microsoft,
you could use the free
[WindowSlider](https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/windowslider/)
for scrolling the entire desktop.

Comment: This will snap the window to the mouse cursor, and the arrow keys will move the mouse cursor too. because the mouse cursor won't move outside of the screenborder, this unfortunately is not the solution.

Comment: It won't help with the bottom section, but as the mouse cursor snaps to the center of the window, at least he'll be able to see the invisible section on the right this way. Not a full solution yet though.

Comment: Poster: Try [WindowSlider](https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/windowslider/) for scrolling the entire desktop.

Comment: That WindowSlider app is neat. If you add that to the answer, I'll retract my vote as that is actually the solution.

Comment: @LPChip: Done as suggested.

Comment: -1 removed... but no, I'm actually going to make it a +1 because this is a really good app.

Comment: @harrymc How to slide the window up and down?

Comment: The Shift-Right-click method uses arrow keys, but will snap back the window into the desktop. WindowSlider is better.

Comment: @harrymc you have to press enter after moving the window to the new position. I have no idea why you have to confirm window movement, but this makes it stick.

Comment: WindowSlider can not slide windows up and down.

Comment: @Creepercdn it can't indeed, but it can center the app on screen, allowing you to see a bit more vertically than before. It really is the best in what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Run the software in a virtual instance where it's sized to fit the entire window, then maximize the instance Window.

Alternatively, you can change [display scaling](https://superuser.com/questions/1190895/is-it-possible-to-scale-specific-apps-on-windows-10) for the application as needed.  This can also be done at the system level, as well as possibly by discrete GPU (e.g., nVidia settings).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get this to work, is if the application has the ability to maximize. You can doubleclick the titlebar to maximize or use the context menu in the taskbar.

This will ensure that the entire window is placed on the screen, but if the application was not build well enough, it will still fall outside of the screen realestate.

If your graphics card is a modern NVidia or AMD one, you can enable super resolution to give you a higher desktop resolution. Alternatively, use an external monitor that has a higher resolution.

If none of these options work, contact the developer and ask them to program in scrollbars so you can at least scroll to the areas not reachable to you.

Comment: Contact the developer is right. The visual design of the application sounds poorly conceived if it is tied to an enormous monitor.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - It could be some sort of niche software which is used by very few people in highly specific jobs. Assuming a large monitor then could be reasonable and even written in the software requirements.